# Add a view dynamically to the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have been developing one list view that on each row of list view (card view) I have one horizontal scrool view that I add some view (Dynamic view) on scrool view (this is Dynamic and count of view one each row is diffrent)
But when I scrool down or up Adapter add extra view on scrool view (I mean for example It should add 2 view and it added but when scrool down or up it added 2 extara view too )

I do not know how to manage this problem.

My code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SicknessResulteHolder holder, int position) {

    //Use the provided View Holder on the onCreateViewHolder method to populate the current row on the RecyclerView
    /**********************************************************************************************************/

    List<String> user_symptoms = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i<frag_recognize_1.list.size() ; i++){

        for (int j = 0 ; j< list.get(position).user_symptoms.size() ; j++){
            if (list.get(position).user_symptoms.get(j) == frag_recognize_1.list.get(i).getSymptoms_id()){
                user_symptoms.add(frag_recognize_1.list.get(i).getTitle());
            }
        }
    }
    /**********************************************************************************************************/


    if (list.get(position).addView){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < list.get(position).user_symptoms.size() ; i++){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.symptoms_row,null,false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(user_symptoms.get(i)));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            holder.scrollSymptoms.addView(linearLayout);
        }
        list.get(position).setAddView(false);
    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are adding view when View Holder is binded. Try doing it when View holder is Created.

```
@Override
public YourAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//your addView goes here
}
```

Comment: tank you very much , The problem was solved , I should enter my codes to this method